Add new row to .csv using encoding/csv
I'm writing a little program providing two methods to read and write to a .csv file.
Reading works fine, but I have problems adding a new row to the .csv file.
The file is located in the project root in /data/data.csv.
Expected
The method appends a new row to the .csv with the current timestamp and the passed quantity in separate columns.
Actual
The method returns without error but the file is not changed.
Below is the function writing to the file.
func (r *CSVRepository) Add(quantity int) error {
    // Open the CSV file
    file, err := os.OpenFile(r.csvPath, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    // Append a new line to the CSV file
    writer := csv.NewWriter(file)
    defer writer.Flush()

    timestamp := time.Now().String()
    value := strconv.Itoa(quantity)

    err = writer.Write([]string{"1", timestamp, value}) // Open the CSV file

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    return nil
}


Delete the second defer file.Close().

@rocka2q bingo. Quite obvious that this one is not needed.
But can you explain why this statement breaks the writing?
If you add your answer, I will mark it

It breaks because you cannot flush the csv.Writer after the file has been closed.

The Go Programming Language Specification: Defer statements: "deferred functions are invoked immediately before the surrounding function returns, in the reverse order they were deferred." Deferred functions in your code are invoked: file.Close(), writer.Flush(), and file.Close(). The writer.Error() from writer.Flush() is write csvPath: bad file descriptor. In Go, always check for errors.

@CeriseLimón, writer.Flush() does not return errors; instead the errors can be easily checked as explained here

The error occurs when writer.Flush() is invoked, because the file is already closed.
This is a silent error that you MAY check if you call writer.Error after invoking writer.Flush() as explained in the documentation.
The writer.Flush() is invoked after the file is closed because of the second defer file.Close() in your function.
@rocka2q provided in a comment a link to this page that explains how defer works.
In the code block below, I mimicked what your function is doing, by replacing all your defers with direct calls to the functions you are trying to defer. Also handled the silent error for a better understanding.  You may run in debug and check step by step what is going on:
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

type CSVRepository struct {
    csvPath string
}

func main() {
    myCSVRepo := CSVRepository{
        csvPath: "./myFile.csv",
    }

    err := myCSVRepo.AddEquivalentWithoutDefers(5)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("something went wrong on AddEquivalentWithoutDefers()", err.Error())
    }
}

func (r *CSVRepository) AddEquivalentWithoutDefers(quantity int) error {
    // Open the CSV file
    file, err := os.OpenFile(r.csvPath, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    /* defer file.Close() // Line removed and replaced with: [1] */

    // Append a new line to the CSV file
    writer := csv.NewWriter(file)
    /*  defer writer.Flush() // Line removed and replaced with: [2] */

    timestamp := time.Now().String()
    value := strconv.Itoa(quantity)

    err = writer.Write([]string{"1", timestamp, value}) // Open the CSV file
    if err != nil {
        writer.Flush() // [2]
        file.Close()   // [1]
        return err
    }
    /* defer file.Close() // Line removed and replaced with: [3] */

    file.Close()               // [3]
    writer.Flush()             // [2]
    if writer.Error() != nil { // << you can check if any error occurs when flushing like this
        return writer.Error() // oups...trying to write in a file closed one line above
    }
    file.Close() // [1]
    return nil
}

